# How to tell how long it's been since I did a git pull

Tags: git

I'm surprised that I'm having such a hard time figuring this out.  I see an error in my test environment but not on my local machine.  I wonder how my local environment compares to the test environment.  How can I see how a given local git repository compares with origin?

Comment: What about `git fetch` followed by `git diff origin/master` (or whatever your branch name is)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I see how a given local git repository compares with origin

Well, you really can't; the question is too broad, and is rather vague. But you can certainly make comparison for a particular branch.

There are four worlds to consider:

- The remote repository (e.g. something that lives on GitHub).
- The remote-tracking branches on your local machine. They have names like `origin/master`. They are in the local repository.
- Your local branches. They have names like `master`. They are in the local repository.
- The actual files visible to you in the project folder. These are volatile and are merely temporary copies created when you checkout a branch, in order to give you something to work on. They are not part of the local repository; they are just a device for letting you communicate with the local repository.

After a `git fetch`, the remote tracking branches are all identical to the corresponding branches on the actual remote. So to learn the state of the remote, `git fetch` and then examine `origin/master` and similar.

After a `git pull`, the remote tracking branch has been merged into the corresponding local branch. This does not mean that the remote tracking branch and the local branch are now identical; on the contrary, the local branch might now have a merge commit that the remote tracking branch does not have, not to mention any other unpushed commits in the local branch.

So to learn the difference between the state of `master` on the remote machine and the state of `master` on your local machine, do *not* pull. Instead, fetch. Now just look at the differences between `origin/master` and `master` (with `git diff`).